# how to completely disable autofill in android

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager

I had problem with AutoFill in android and it cause

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: null asks to run as user 5 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

I resolved it by adding `android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"` to TextInputLayout in XML.
 but when try to select all text in TextInputLayout, it force AutoFill to start and get the error again.

So first is there any way to totally disable AutoFill for my app ?!

Second I want to know is there any way to avoid the permission error I look at android AutoFill Doc and can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:
INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

You could see it in your log message.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I try what you say, it's not working.